# shinyTree: more than 3 hierarchical levels

Tags: shiny, jstree, shinytree

I have the following code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTree)

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {  
  output$level_tree <- renderTree({ 
    list('1 level'= list( 
      '1.1 level' = structure(
        list('1.1.1 level'='1', 
            '1.1.2 level'='2')),stopened=TRUE),  
      '1.2 level' = structure(
        list('1.2.1 level'='3')),stopened=TRUE))) 
  })
})

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    h4('Levels'),
    shinyTree("level_tree", checkbox = TRUE)
  )
)
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is there any way to the add to the hierarchical tree the following levels:

- 1.1.1.**1**,
- 1.1.1.**1.1**,
- 1.1.1.**1.1.1**

I unsuccessfully tried:

```
list('1 level'= list( 
      '1.1 level' = structure(
        list('1.1.1 level'=list(
                '1.1.1.1 level=list(
                    '1.1.1.1.1'='1')), 
            '1.1.2 level'='2')),stopened=TRUE),  
      '1.2 level' = structure(
        list('1.2.1 level'='3')),stopened=TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you have to nest everyhing in lists or structures.

Your data was in a wrong format. This data should work.

```
list(
  '1 level'= list( 
    '1.1 level' = structure(
      list('1.1.1 level'=
             list('1.1.1.1 level'=
                    list('1.1.1.1.1'='1')),
           '1.1.2 level'='2'),stopened=TRUE)
  ),
  '1.2 level' = structure(
    list('1.2.1 level' = '3'),stopened=TRUE)
)
```

---

**Shiny-App**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyTree)
library(shinyjs)

trl <- list(
  '1 level'= list( 
    '1.1 level' = structure(
      list('1.1.1 level'=
             list('1.1.1.1 level'=
                    list('1.1.1.1.1'='1')),
           '1.1.2 level'='2'),stopened=TRUE)
  ),
  '1.2 level' = structure(
    list('1.2.1 level' = '3'),stopened=TRUE)
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyTree("tree")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tree <- renderTree({
    trl
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```